# cmake: unable to find_package()

Tags: cmake

I am trying to find the required library for my cmake file but i am unable to find it.

This is my cmake code:

```
find_package(myLib REQUIRED)
```

This is the error msg which is being shown:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):


By not providing "FindmyLib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "myLib", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "myLib" with any
  of the following names:

    myLibConfig.cmake
    mylib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "myLib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "myLib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "myLib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Can i know how to fix this.

Comment: Difficult to answer this question without more information. Start by having a look here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html

Comment: Please read first the documentation and then ask again https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have not added the folder where you placed the custom `FindmyLib.cmake` to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.
For example if you have placed `FindmyLib.cmake` in the folder `cmake/modules` relative to the `CMakeList.txt` you are using, add

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules
)
```

in the `CMakeList.txt`